# How to save transparent and originals colors of images in render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, image, transparency, color, color-management

In blender i chose 'color management' - standard. I used Eevee
Then added "images as planes". Images have transparent parts, so i used principled BSDF with alpha. But in the render, images didn't match colors as original images. Also images change the color if i change world color. I can use just image texture without principled BSDF (colors match colors of original images), but transparent part turn into black color.
How to save transparent and originals colors without using white world color and transparent background in render properties?
[image: the first one without principled bsdf and alpha, the second with]

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the world to influence the color, you can plug the image into the *Emission* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]